# What is the syntax for using the results of object method inside the object itself?

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {
  foot: [1, 3, 5],
  shoe: [7, 9, 11],
  dump: // a function that sets obj.dump as the value of (this.foot[1] + this.shoe[0])
        // (otherwise known as `10`)
}
```

Things I have tried (`IIFE`, anon function, etc), referring to `obj.dump` returns the function used to do the add.

I would like `obj.dump` to instead return `10`

What is the proper syntax for that?

---

*Side note, how would I search for this? What could this pattern be called?*

Comment: Maybe you want an accessor function (aka getter/setter)? it would just be `get dump() { return this.foot[1] + this.shoe[0]; }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey what sorcery is this?! If you make it a response I'll set it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The question has been closed as a duplicate. Kinglish was only able to add their answer due to the fact that they were writing the answer before VLAZ closed it.